# How to get a data I put when I start intent for TweetComposer on onActivirtResult in android

Tags: android, android-intent, twitter

I'm using TweetComposert.Builder to share a link with intent as below.

```
Intent intent= new TweetComposer.Builder(activity)
            .text("http://travel.asiaone.com/travel/destinations/5-ways-singaporeans-can-discover-iceland-budget")
            .createIntent()

    intent.putExtra("ABCD", refNo);

    activity.startActivityForResult(intent, Constants.REQUEST_TWITTER_SHARE );
```

Result for it should go to onActivityResult in MyMainActivity.

```
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {...}
```

I expected I can get a data I put when I executed 'startActivityForResult' like data.getIntExtra("ABCD", 0), but there is nothing.

Is there any idea for it?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You puts the data for an activity which is started. So if you want to get result, you should set result in activity which was started. Link about method [setResult()](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html#setResult(int)). So read twitter documentation. May be it doesn't return any data in intent.